# transform script status_message not updating in SOAP response body in servicenow

Tags: servicenow

I am created a `onBefore` transform script.

```
(function runTransformScript(source, map, log, target /*undefined onStart*/ ) {
    if(source.u_incident.nil()){
        status_message="The Record is not inerted";
        error_message="ERR001 Cell number can't be empty!";
        ignore = true;
    } 
})(source, map, log, target);
```

I am sending the request from SOAP UI, if the `u_incident` value is empty it is not creating the new one as we mentioned `ignore=true`, but in the SOAP response body I am not getting `status_message` and `error_message` as expected the default messages are coming.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
(function runTransformScript(source, map, log, target /*undefined onStart*/ ) {
    if(source.u_incident.nil()){
        response.status_message="The Record is not inerted";
        response.error_message="ERR001 Cell number can't be empty!";
        ignore = true;
    } 
})(source, map, log, target);
```